# getSelection().collapseToEnd() does not work

Tags: javascript, html, selection, contenteditable

What I am trying to do is move the caret to the end of the string when the element is focused.

`collapseToEnd()` does not work. Instead, if you uncomment `getSelection().collapseToEnd()`, it seems to remove the selection altogether or favors the user selection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')

div.addEventListener('focus', moveCaretToEnd)

function moveCaretToEnd() {
  getSelection().setBaseAndExtent(
    div.childNodes[0], div.textContent.length,
    div.childNodes[0], div.textContent.length-1
  )
  // getSelection().collapseToEnd()
  // getSelection().collapse(div.childNodes[0], div.textContent.length) // also does not work
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size:  3rem;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>This is a test</div>
```